# RSA using bouncy castle with key stored in CSP blog

Tags: c#, bouncycastle, public-key-encryption

I have a private key in a [csp format](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc250013.aspx). I need migrate to Bouncy Castle. But I don't find any function to import this format.

Please, can you help me to traslate this code?

```
using (RSACryptoServiceProvider privatekey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider()) {
    privatekey.ImportCspBlob("chave em csp");
    Byte[] buffer = Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8").GetBytes(textEdit1.Text);
    Byte[] signature = privatekey.SignData(buffer, "SHA1");
    return Convert.ToBase64String(signature);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can start with this: [C# Sign Data with RSA using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830510/c-sharp-sign-data-with-rsa-using-bouncycastle), it tells how to sign using Bouncy Castle, to import the key to Bouncy Castle, you need to look at the DotNetUtilities class on Org.BouncyCastle.Security namespace.