# Create RSA public key and private key

Tags: c#, .net-core, rsa, bouncycastle

Im trying to make a SHA1withRSA sign/verify function on ASP.NET core using BouncyCastle library, 1st of all I need to make a keypair, I am using this page to generate the key:
https://travistidwell.com/jsencrypt/demo/

However from BouncyCastle example code I found ([C# Sign Data with RSA using BouncyCastle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8830510/c-sharp-sign-data-with-rsa-using-bouncycastle)), from the Public and Private key text generated, I couldn't make the key files, which as I understand, would be a .CER file for public key and .PEM for private key.

So could you please suggest me a way to make the .CER and .PEM file? Also, I haven't found a complete example about signing SHA1withRSA using BouncyCastle library - or just core C#, I'd be so grateful if you could suggest me a complete example, thank you so much.

Comment: The linked site generates keys in PKCS#1 (private) and X.509 (public) format. Both should be importable into .NET Core (in contrast to .NET Framework) as DER, unless you are using a too old version. Therefore, which .NET Core version are you using? And do you want to apply BouncyCastle even if it works with .NET Core alone?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I am using .NET Core 2.2, could u please give me some advice to make the key files?  Yes, I only need it to work wit .NET Core.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The linked website generates private keys in PKCS#1 format and public keys in X.509/SPKI format, each PEM encoded.

.NET Core only supports the import of PKCS#1 and X.509 keys as of version 3.0. For .NET Core 2.2, the easiest way is to apply BouncyCastle. For loading the PEM keys the `PemReader` of BouncyCastle can be used.

**Option 1:**

With BouncyCastle's `DotNetUtilities` class, `RSAParameters` instances can be derived and thus `RSACryptoServiceProvider` instances:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
...
public static RSACryptoServiceProvider GetRSACryptoServiceProviderFromPem(string pem, bool isPrivate)
{
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
    object key = pemReader.ReadObject();

    RSAParameters rsaParameters = isPrivate ? 
        DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)(((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)key).Private)) : 
        DotNetUtilities.ToRSAParameters((RsaKeyParameters)key);

    RSACryptoServiceProvider rsaKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
    rsaKey.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

    return rsaKey;
}
```

`RSACryptoServiceProvider` in turn has methods for signing/verifying:

```cs
RSACryptoServiceProvider privateCSP = GetRSACryptoServiceProviderFromPem(privateKey, true);
RSACryptoServiceProvider publicCSP = GetRSACryptoServiceProviderFromPem(publicKey, false);

byte[] dataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
byte[] signature = privateCSP.SignData(dataToSign, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
bool verified = publicCSP.VerifyData(dataToSign, signature, HashAlgorithmName.SHA1, RSASignaturePadding.Pkcs1);
```

---

**Option 2:**

Alternatively, the `RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters` and the `RsaKeyParameters` classes of BouncyCastle can be used *directly*:

```cs
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Security;
...
public static AsymmetricKeyParameter GetAsymmetricKeyParameterFromPem(string pem, bool isPrivate)
{
    PemReader pemReader = new PemReader(new StringReader(pem));
    object key = pemReader.ReadObject();

    return isPrivate ? ((AsymmetricCipherKeyPair)key).Private : (AsymmetricKeyParameter)key;
}
```

as well as classes for signing and verifying provided by BouncyCastle's `SignerUtilities`:

```cs
RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters privateKeyParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)GetAsymmetricKeyParameterFromPem(privateKey, true);
RsaKeyParameters publicKeyParameters = (RsaKeyParameters)GetAsymmetricKeyParameterFromPem(publicKey, false);

ISigner signer = SignerUtilities.GetSigner("SHA1withRSA");
signer.Init(true, privateKeyParameters);
byte[] dataToSign = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog");
signer.BlockUpdate(dataToSign, 0, dataToSign.Length);
byte[] signature = signer.GenerateSignature();

signer.Init(false, publicKeyParameters);
signer.BlockUpdate(dataToSign, 0, dataToSign.Length);
bool verified = signer.VerifySignature(signature);
Console.WriteLine(verified);
```

---

Both implementations are executable under .NET Core 2.2.

Comment: The 2 solutions can be compared online on .NET Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/7rHq89

Comment: thank you so much for your effort! It works great!